# Django Cart - multiple configuration options for a product

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I want to create a Django web-application where users can add items to a cart.

Without the models `Colour` and `Size` this works so far.

My Problem is, that i can not figure out how to implement the configuration-options (for example) `Colour` and `Size` the right way.

I added both "Options" with a Many-to-One relationship. I now can add multiple colours and sizes for a Product, but do not know how to save the choosen "Option" in an `CartEntry`

This is what i got so far:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Colour(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rel_colour")
    option = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.colour)

class Size(models.Model):
    product =models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rel_size")
    option = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.size)



class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' - ' + str(self.user)


class CartEntry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.quantity) + ', ' + str(self.product.name)
```

Maybe i can not user relations for `CartEntry` here?

Answer (score 2):

why not do like this:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        colour = models.ForeignKey(Colour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)

    class Colour(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)

    class Size(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```

so every product has different colour and size. or if you want make a Product as a "parent" you can add 1 more model like let say VariantProduct

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)

    class VariantProduct(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        colour = models.ForeignKey(Colour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```

Comment: I had this before, but i actually have more "Options" then Colour and Size and the amount of Products i have to create for each possibility is to high.